# Using rules inside Module or Block

Tags: scoping

I have a rather long piece of code inside a `Module`, and I want to provide different parameters to the different pieces inside the `Module`. Lets call the inside `expr`, and the parameter(s) I would like to choose `a`. Then I would try something like this:

```
func[a_] := Module[{a1 = a},
expr /. {k -> a1};
]
```

`expr` is a rather long analytic expression depending on `k`, into which I want to plug different values `a` into. Well, long story short, the above approach doesn't work, as the rule is simply not applied inside the `Module`. I have also tried different variations of this and used `Block`, but non worked. Is there a way to make this work, by using rules?

I am fairly new to all this `Module` and `Block` business, so some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It is corrected in the above version.

Comment: remove `;` after `{k->a1}`?

Comment: Take a look at this function in the function repository: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ExpressionToFunction

Comment: `expr /. k->a1` does not modify `expr`. Instead, it generates a new expression, which you need to assign to a new variable: `newexpr = expr /. k->a1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are applied within `Module`. For example:

```
func[a_] := Module[
  {
   a1 = a
   },
  1 + k + k^2 /. k -> a1
  ]
```

And then

```
func[1]
(* 3 *)

func[2]
(* 7 *)
```

However, the way you have stated the problem there is no need to use `Rule` at all.

As I understand your question you could simply write:

```
func2[k_] := 1 + k + k^2
```

and then

```
func2[1]
(* 3 *)

func2[2]
(* 7 *)
```